SQL Server Trace Flag 5013
We have been advised to apply Trace Flag 5013 to our Production servers running SQL Server 2017 or above. My issue here is that this flag undocumented, so we are not able to verify exactly what it does. It does make our third-party product more stable, but we don’t know if we’d be introducing any other undesired effects onto our estates. I’d like to ask if anyone out there has had any experience with this flag?


My issue here is that this flag undocumented, so we are not able to verify exactly what it does.

Depends on who told you to enable it. If Microsoft Support told you to do it, then it should be a mostly trustworthy option to enable it, but you could also ask what it does... though they are under no obligation to give you a deep dive into it. If it's a 3rd party then you should definitely ask them.

It does make our third-party product more stable, but we don’t know if we’d be introducing any other undesired effects onto our estates.

It sounds as though your system is setup to use some type of EKM setup, probably something like Azure Key Vault (AKV) and you're running into intermittent performance issues or errors when said EKM communications is slow/failed. You're probably better off looking into/fixing that issue than doing anything else.
If you're not having that issue, that trace flag won't help you.
